# tensorflow ImportError: /home/user/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, anaconda

Trying to build tensorflow from source in an anaconda3 environment on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the build was successful but when I try:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

It gives me errors:

> ImportError: /home/user/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version
>   `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found

I've looked through and figured it could be the `libgcc` is old, so I tried `conda install libgcc` which does install a new library with `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` listed; However it seems anaconda installed it into the virtual environment but *tensorflow* is looking for it in the `anaconda3/lib` folder, how do I solve this problem? Is there an easy fix without reinstalling anaconda and rebuild from source (which takes a very long time)?

```
(tensorflow) user@user-VirtualBox:~$ strings /home/user/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

`conda install libgcc` installs the new `libgcc` into the virtual environment folder:

```
(tensorflow) user@user-VirtualBox:~$ strings /home/user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
```

As you may have noticed, `/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/libstdc++.so.6` does have  `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` listed but `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6` doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I temporarily solved the problem following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error#answer-764572), here is what I did:

1) activate virtual environment:

```
source activate virtual-env-name
```

2) Install a newer version of `libstdc++.so.6`, in my case the `libgcc` version is `5+` with *anaconda3*:

```
conda install libgcc
```

3) Go to the `anaconda3/lib` folder:

```
cd ~/anaconda3/lib
```

4) Back up the `libstdc++.so.6`:

```
mv -vf libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.old
```

5) Link the freshly installed `libstdc++.so.6` in the virtual environment library here, `virtual-env-name` is the virtual environment name:

```
ln -s ~/anaconda3/envs/virtual-env-name/lib/libstdc++.so.6 ./libstdc++.so.6
```

Hope this is helpful to somebody else who has the same problem.

Comment: Instead of modifying links I would try with `export LD_PRELOAD=/opt/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.25` before running your command