# Tensorflow can't be loaded

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, tensorflow, terminal

I installed tensorflow using pip (even different versions of tf), but whenever I'm loading it in the server, I get the following. I spent a whole day on this, couldn't figure out so far. Hopefully someone smart will do it easily!

```
> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/afs/umich.edu/user/b/m/bmodene/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "/afs/umich.edu/user/b/m/bmodene/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/afs/umich.edu/user/b/m/bmodene/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/afs/umich.edu/user/b/m/bmodene/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/afs/umich.edu/user/b/m/bmodene/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/afs/umich.edu/user/b/m/bmodene/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.17' not found (required by /afs/umich.edu/user/b/m/bmodene/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)
```

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

I tried following these instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

Comment: you're installing on linux?

Comment: there's a lot of directions on that page, you're going to have to be more specific on what you did

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tensorflow ImportError: /home/user/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version \`GLIBCXX\_3.4.20' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45906751/tensorflow-importerror-home-user-anaconda3-bin-lib-libstdc-so-6-version)

Answer (score 0):

In the page you're referring to there is a section under "Build the pip package" saying:

> NOTE on gcc 5 or later: the binary pip packages available on the TensorFlow website are built with gcc 4, which uses the older ABI. To make your build compatible with the older ABI, you need to add --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" to your bazel build command. ABI compatibility allows custom ops built against the TensorFlow pip package to continue to work against your built package.

It is unclear from your question if you built the package yourself, but if yes, have you tried this option?